# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
....

client.ContactService.AddWithDupCheck(setter =>
{
    setter.Set(c => c.FirstName, fKvp.Value);
    setter.Set(c => c.LastName, lKvp.Value);
    setter.Set(c => c.Email, eKvp.Value);
}, "Email");
```

However I get the error indication on the first 'setter' after the opening bracket:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Collections.IDictionary' because it is not a delegate type.

The `AddWithDupCheck` method accepts a first argument that can be either

```
Action<IFieldSetter<Contact>>
```

or
    IDictionary

It thinks I'm trying to pass an `IDictionary`, so what do I need to do to fix the error?

Comment: Is the second parameter, the `"Email"` string causing the problem? I dont see any other params in the definition for the action

Comment: No, the AddWithDupCheck method accepts two parameters and the 2nd must be a string

Answer (score 1):

I didn't solve the specific issue (I'm trying to add a subscriber to the Infusionsoft system), however I got it working by using this:

```
            XmlRpcStruct subscriberData = new XmlRpcStruct();
            subscriberData.Add("FirstName", fKvp.Value);
            subscriberData.Add("LastName", lKvp.Value);
            subscriberData.Add("Email", eKvp.Value);

            // add or update (update if subscriber Email matches existing record)
            client.ContactService.AddWithDupCheck(subscriberData, "Email");
```